# Make plot defining X values based on column numbers/names in R

Tags: r, plot, axis

I´m trying to make a plot in R where the X axis values correspond to specific columns with horizontal lines connecting the y axis by row (like using the matplot fucntion). For example:

```
set.seed(23); dt <- matrix(runif(18, 0, 1), nrow = 3, ncol=6)

> dt
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.5766037 0.7107246 0.9635445 0.9966112 0.3904731 0.1392785
[2,] 0.2230729 0.8194490 0.9781304 0.8659590 0.3147697 0.5181206
[3,] 0.3318966 0.4237206 0.8405219 0.7014217 0.8459473 0.5935508
```

I want to make a plot were x-2=col 1,  x-1= col 2, x0=col 3, x1=col 4, x2=col 5, x3=col 6, etc with a line connecting the y values for each row.

Do you have an idea how this can be done in a easy way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(23)
dt <- matrix(runif(18, 0, 1), nrow = 3, ncol=6)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(dt) %>%                              # save it as dataframe
  mutate(id = factor(row_number())) %>%         # add row number as a variable
  gather(key,value,-id) %>%                     # reshape dataset
  ggplot(aes(key, value, group=id, col=id)) +   # plot data by grouping on id
  geom_point() +                                # add points
  geom_line()                                   # add lines
```

[image]

The color (id) represents the row in your initial table. X axis represents the columns in your initial table.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But is there any other way without using the ggplot2 package? I think it's extremely difficult to make changes in the graphs using the ggplot2 package syntax

Comment: I'm a ggplot user, but you can run the process up to the point before the ggplot commands and save it as a new dataset. Then you can use it to create plots using the base R commands.

Comment: ok thanks. I just found out that the matplot function can also be a simple solution: matplot(t(dt), type="l")